# Create Bucket in Couchbase using Http Post Request

Tags: couchbase

I  want to create a bucket in couchbase on runtime using a simple http post request. I have used the following link to do the task [link](https://developer.couchbase.com/documentation/server/current/rest-api/rest-bucket-create.html)

Raw request I generated on postman is as follows:-

> http://:8091/pools/default/buckets?name=newbucket&bucketType=membase&ramQuotaMB=20&authType=none&replicaNumber=2&proxyPort=11215

But its giving me error:-

```
{
    "errors": {
        "authType": "invalid authType"
    },
    "summaries": {
        "ramSummary": {
            "total": 20191379456,
            "otherBuckets": 16710107136,
            "nodesCount": 2,
            "perNodeMegs": 0,
            "thisAlloc": 0,
            "thisUsed": 0,
            "free": 3481272320
        },
        "hddSummary": {
            "total": 158247145472,
            "otherData": 11366997180,
            "otherBuckets": 68794932977,
            "thisUsed": 0,
            "free": 78085215315
        }
    }
}
```

I have used the basic auth as the username and password of the couchbase console.

Any idea whats wrong with the call.

Comment: Are you using Couchbase 5.x?

Comment: 4.6.4-4590 Enterprise Edition

Answer (score 2):

I think the problem is that you're passing the parameters in the URL and not as part of the POST body. Since you're using Postman, check the "x-www-form-urlencoded" option and enter the various values there.

Here's a screenshot of an example, which returns a 202 (Accepted) response:

[image]